# SSH configuration forwarding

Tags: ssh, forwarding

Is there a way/option/wrapper for ssh that will permit not only agent-forwarding but also configuration forwarding?

For instance, consider a `workstation` and a `server`. The workstation `~/.ssh/config` defines the hosts `somehost` and `server` but **the server config file is empty**. Is it possible while on `server` to use `workstation`'s config file in this manner:

```
user@workstation$ ssh server # server is defined in .ssh/config on workstation

 successful login on server

user@server$ ssh somehost # somehost is defined in .ssh/config on workstation
                          #                  but NOT in .ssh/config on server

 successful login on somehost

user@somehost$ _
```

i.e. I WANT to refer to `workstation`'s config file while being on `server`.

Comment: You question isn't clear. Do you refer to the client (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`) or the server configuration file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) on `server`, i.e. the intermediate hop?

Comment: @0xC0000022L, sorry for the confusion. I WANT to refer to `workstation`'s config file while being on `server`.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility I can think of from the top of my head that doesn't involve actual copying would be to create a tunnel from the client (`workstation`) to `somehost` via `ssh -w ...`, thereby allowing you to connect "directly" from `workstation` to `somehost`.

So you dig a tunnel `server` to `somehost` and thereby make `somehost` available for `workstation`. That is if port forwarding hasn't been disabled or restricted.

The only other possibility that comes to mind is to copy the config file over, using `scp`, and then start the `ssh` client on `server` using `ssh -F <your-copied-config>`. As a variation on that theme you could of course parse the config files on `workstation` and pass the options using `-o ...`.